# Search profile based on image on social media and display profile information

Tags: flutter, dart, user-profile

I want to search users profile based on image on social media and display their information on a different page, but it doesn't display the user's complete profile like it's on social media. For every social media a different page and on that page user's specific data but in a formatted way like it's on their profile on let's say Twitter.
So far this what I have done :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  // Get the image file from the user.
  File imageFile = await FilePicker.pickImage();

  // Convert the image file to a base64 string.
  String base64Image = base64Encode(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());

  // Create a URL to the Google Images search by image API.
  String url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=image&imageUrl=data:image/jpeg;base64,$base64Image';

  // Make the request to the API.
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);

  // Check if the request was successful.
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Parse the response body as JSON.
    Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);

    // Get the list of results.
    List<dynamic> results = json['items'];

    // Loop through the results and display the profile information.
    for (var result in results) {
      String profileUrl = result['link'];
      String profileName = result['title'];
      print('Profile URL: $profileUrl');
      print('Profile Name: $profileName');
    }
  } else {
    // Print an error message.
    print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```